# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError In Hibernate Search module 5.9.0 with spring boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-search

I am trying to put Hibernate Search/Lucene Search into my Spring boot JPA Project But I get 500 error stating

> "status": 500,"exception": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
>           "message": "org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.(Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionImplementor;)V",

I am not knowing which dependency is creating the problem .Please help me fix this.Hibernate Search ORM version 5.9 I am using

My SearchConfig:

```
@Autowired
    private EntityManager bentityManager;

    @Bean
    CandidateLuceneSearchService CandidateLuceneSearchService() {
        CandidateLuceneSearchService CandidateLuceneSearchService = new CandidateLuceneSearchService(bentityManager);
        CandidateLuceneSearchService.initializeHibernateSearch();
        return CandidateLuceneSearchService;
    }
```

My SearchServicecode:

```
@Transactional
    public List<Candidate> fuzzySearch(String searchTerm) {
          FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
                  org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.
                  getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
       // FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(centityManager);

        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Candidate.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query =
                qb
                .keyword()
                .onFields("keyskill")
                .matching(searchTerm)
                .createQuery();

        //Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("keyskill")
               // .matching(searchTerm).createQuery();

        javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Candidate.class);

        // execute search

        List<Candidate> BaseballCardList = null;
        try {
            BaseballCardList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            ;// do nothing

        }

        return BaseballCardList;


    }
```

Here is my POM.XML File

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath />
</parent>

<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>

  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1102-jdbc4</version>
  </dependency>



  <!-- Commons Libraries -->

  <!-- Spring boot libs start -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>

  </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>

  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0.Final</version>

  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are either mixing up different Hibernate JARs with unsupported versions or attempted to use old version of Hibernate not supported by Spring Boot. Review your project dependencies.

The particular constructor of [`SessionDelegatorBaseImpl` was introduced in Hibernate 5.3](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5e8781f8fa123d4e437f669b57cfa1456a169873/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionDelegatorBaseImpl.java#L88). Perhaps you need to update Hibernate Search version.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not using the right version of Hibernate ORM.

Hibernate Search 5.9 should be used with Hibernate ORM 5.2 (5.2.3 or later, the previous versions won't work).

See our website for a detailed compatibility matrix: http://hibernate.org/search/releases/#compatibility-matrix

Comment: Should i  migrate to Spring boot 2 instead of 1.5.8?

Comment: It's a broad question, but unless you have other constraints, yes, you should use the latest version. According to the [Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) the default version of Hibernate ORM in this version is 5.3.7.Final, so it's probably only compatible with ORM 5.3.x (which means you'll need Hibernate Search 5.11.0.Final).

Comment: If you stick to Spring Boot 1.5.8, [according to the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE//reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html) the default version of Hibernate ORM will be 5.0.12.Final, which probably means it's only compatible with ORM 5.0.x or 5.1.x, which means you'll be stuck with Hibernate Search 5.6.6.Final. I suppose there might be an intermediary version of Spring Boot that is for sure compatible with Hibernate ORM 5.2, but if I was you I wouldn't bother.